# Dynamic html table generated in php is creating empty columns

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I have a MySql database storing customer information, and I want do display this information in a table, easy enough, however I've run into an issue where every even column is generating without a value, and the information that was meant to go there is placed in the next column.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
  function getcustomers(){
    $servername = "127.0.0.1";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "chm";

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>ID</th>";
        echo "<th>Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Last</th>";
        echo "<th>Spouse</th>";
        echo "<th>Home</th>";
        echo "<th>Buisness</th>";
        echo "<th>Cell</th>";
        echo "<th>Email</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $row["id"] . "<td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row["firstname"] . "<td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row["lastname"] . "<td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row["spousename"] . "<td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row["homephone"] . "<td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row["buisnessphone"] . "<td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row["mobilephone"] . "<td>";
          echo "<td>" . $row["email"] . "<td>";
          echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "<table>";
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();
  }
?>
```

And this is what the table looks like:

[image: table]

Comment: Cool story bro. Thanks for the status report. Was there a *question*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not closing your `td` tags with `</td>`. The same problem exists with the `table` tag. You need to close them with the closing tag (with a `/`) and not an opening tag. Also note that it's spelled business.

Comment: Ahh, oops. Thank you!